# Jquery validate plugin for 'at least 1' entry in a listbox

Tags: jquery, validation

I think I've done quite an exhaustive search but haven't found an answer yet.

I have a listbox (select multiple) of URI addresses which can be added to by an input field above it.  (ie: type in an URI address, click the ADD button, the URI is added to the list box below).

Using the JQuery Validate Plugin, I have defined the select box, selectboxUriList, as

```
selectboxUriList: {
    required: true,
    rangelength: [1, 6]
}
```

As well as error messages :

```
selectboxUriList: {
    required: "Required field",
    minlength: "Must have at least 1 URI entry"
}
```

And various iterations of minLength, maxLegth, etc.  Yet even after entering an item, the validation fails *unless* I manually click an item in the list box.  Then it passes immediately.

```
$('[name="btnUriAdd"]').click(function() {
    var uri = $('#txtUriEntry').val();
    $('#selectboxUriList).append('<option value="'+ uri + '">'+  uri + '</option>');
    //$("#selectboxUriList").selectmenu('refresh', true);
    //$('#txtUriEntry').val('');
    //$('#btnUriAdd').attr('disabled', true);
            // manually call validate on the element??
    $('#sendForm').validate().element('#selectboxUriList');
});
```

I've gone through several suggestion on StackOverflow but most seem to rely on a user physically selecting an item.  I just want to validate that the user has entered at least one URI address into the list box.

[Submitted without manually clicking item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se0Tj.png)

[After manually clicking item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n28tA.png)

I've tried using .change(), .on('change', function ()... etc

Would appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think I came up with a solution that works for me.

Created a custom JQuery Validate plugin rule definition:

```
selUriList: {
    uriListCheck: true
},
```

Then defined the rule itself:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('uriListCheck', function(value) {
    var hasOptions = !!$('#selUriList option').filter(function() {
        return !this.disabled;
    }).length;
    if (hasOptions <= 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "At least one base URI is required");
```

Then had the rule called whenever the ADD button was called :

```
$('[name="btnUriAdd"]').click(function() {
    var uri = $('#txtUriEntry').val();
    $('#selUriList').append('<option value="' + uri + '">' + uri + '</option>');
    $('#txtUriEntry').val('');
    $('#btnUriAdd').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#sendForm').validate().element('#selUriList');
});
```

Posting this in case it helps anyone else.